# Function declaration vs function definition JS

Tags: javascript, conceptual

What is difference between function declaration and function definition in JavaScript? I read chapter 5.3.2 [from this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)

> When nested, however, function **declarations** may
>   only appear at the top level of the function they are nested within. That is, function
>   **definitions** may not appear within if statements, while loops, or any other statements.

but don't understand difference between declaration and definition... Please, explain it ( note: I understand difference between function expression and function declaration!)

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Comment: Please give me some examples of declaration and in JS!

Comment: `var x = function() { return true; }`. I guess you could say here `x = function` is the declaration, and `return true;` is the definition of that function.

Comment: function definition - body of function without name and function declaration - only name of function, but not body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, they are just using two different terms to refer to the same thing. The official* term is "function declaration".

Source for official is page 98 of the ECMAScript standard.

Comment: "Official term"? Can you back that up with a link to or quote from official documentation?

Comment: declaration and definitions synonims in JS?

Comment: @igor_rb I've never heard "definition" before, but they seem to be synonyms here, yes.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) specifies FunctionDeclaration and FunctionExpression for defining functions.

Comment: In this book declaration and definition words use very often, and it gives some misunderstand for me. Thanks!

Comment: @RobH function declaration is subset for function definition?

Comment: @igor_rb Yeah, both function declarations and expressions are function definitions, according to the spec.

Comment: @igor_rb - I honestly don't know. I think you'd have to ask the authors about the distinction they're making. You can definitely define a function within an `if`. e.g. `var a; if (true) { a = function() { return 'worked' }; } else { a= function() { return; }; } console.log(a());`

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is to distinguish two cases:

- `var f1 = function() {...}`
  This is often referred to as a function expression.
- `function f2() {...}`
  This is often referred to as a function declaration.

Whatever the names you give to it, `var f1` will be hoisted to the top of the wrapping function (but `f1` will be assigned the value of the function only at the line you have written it). **However** the whole function declaration of `f2` will be hoisted to the top of the wrapping function.

There is a great post that explains this more in details [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEven(num){
     if(num%2 === 0){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
```

In the above code `function isEven(num)` is called as function declaration, its like in that line of code you declare that `isEven` you are using is a function.

And the remaining part of the code inside the curly braces is called function definition. Where you provide defintion for the function `isEven`.

In js, we don't seperate the declaration and defintion, because we have hoisting. Hoisting makes your function declaration & definition to be hoisted to the top, so you can use the function even before defining it.

In other programming languages like 'C', you don't have hoisting. So the declarations of functions are made before usage and defintions can be placed where ever we want, inside the file.

And thus the reason for two names and what they mean.